# Java 2d animating an imported image in netbeans

Tags: java, animation

Hi I just want to ask how to move an imported(jpg) image from left to right or bottom-up. I am a beginner in Java 2d. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recognize animation as "differences between frames" and frames are displayed at a certain frame-rate.

So what you would have to do is to implement a timer, recalculate what should be drawn (and how and where) and redraw your canvas. And this over and ovr again.

Some simplified pseudo-code might look like this:

```
while(true){
    myImage.setX(myImage.getX() +1); /* change the x-position to x+1 */
    myImage.setY(myImage.getY() +1); /* change the y-position to y+1 */
    myCanvas.paint(); /* redraw your canvas */
    sleep(1/framerate); /* wait for 1/framerate seconds */ 
}
```

You should put this into a thread, so that your UI stays responsive.

BTW: It does not depend on the IDE you are using (Netbeans).

Comment: You'll find a lot to this topic using your favorite searchengine. If you get problems, your welcome to post your code and get help where you're stuck.